# boto3 AWS client ignoring arguments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials, iot, boto3

My library needs to connect to arbitrary AWS-IoT accounts, so I'm passing the required credentials when I instantiate the AWS client:

```
client = boto3.client('iot',
                      aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,...)
```

According to the boto3 docs *(excerpt below)*, credentials passed in this way should override all other credentials. However this call generates the following log message from Boto3:

```
 "Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials"
```

I *really* don't want boto3 picking-up whatever credentials a user may have happen to have configured on their system - I want it to use just the ones I'm passing to boto3.client(). Any ideas how to ensure this?

*boto3 docs excerpt:*

```
The order in which Boto3 searches for credentials is:

 1. Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method
 2. Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
 3. Environment variables
 4. Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)
 5. AWS config file (~/.aws/config)
 6. Assume Role provider
 7. Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg and ~/.boto)
 8. Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.
```

Comment: Please check your access key and secret key is valid.

Answer (score 2):

From my testing, when passing `aws_access_key_id` & `aws_secret_access_key` parameters to `boto3.client(..)`, it accepts them even if they are incorrect and does not load any other credentials from file.
When an API call is sent, it returns a `NoCredentialsError` exception.

However, when above parameters not passed i.e.`boto3.client('iot')` **AND** a default profile exist in the system, I can see "Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials".

Meaning, as long as your explicitly provide credential parameters, you should be protected from calls executed on the wrong account.